# Как понять что диалоговое окно открыто

Tags: qt

Как понять что диалоговое окно открыто? Версия qt4.7.8.

Вот код:

```
    ManualSetting * dialogManualSetting = new ManualSetting(sensormanager,0);
    dialogManualSetting->setModal(true);
    dialogManualSetting->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    dialogManualSetting->exec();
```

Как понять что окно ManualSetting отобразилось?

Comment: Добавьте сигнал, наследуйте exec и шлите этот сигнал из наследника

Comment: Что значит наследуйте exec ?

Comment: не надо делать setModal оно в exec делается

Comment: чтобы понять, что окно отобразилось переопределите `void QWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)`

Answer (score 0):

Пара вариантов (если вам нужно сигнализировать во вне):

```
class ManualSetting: public QDialog {        
    ...
    // Или так
    int exec() {
        emit showedUp();
        return QDialog::exec();
    }

    // Либо так
    void showEvent(QShowEvent* event) {
        QDialog::showEvent(event);
        emit showedUp();
    }

    // Либо уточните вопрос
signals:
    void showedUp();
}
```

Comment: не exec без толку, после него может много времени пройти, хотя конечно вопрос не совсем понятен, но если например нужно определить размеры внешней (т.е. виндовой) рамки окна, то только showEvent ждать

Comment: @PavelGridin exec() добавил, чтобы показать, что есть разные варианты.

Comment: showEvent вызывается раньше чем происходит отображение окна.